# show view before validation OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I want to create a login for social networks, for example, Twitter, Facebook, etc.

But there are social networks like twitter that do not give me the email.

How can I do so before saving the user to display a form view where to add the email and then save all data of Twitter + email?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you know how to setup omniauth, so I will skip straight to the relevant parts.

In the callback, if user is found for specified uid and provider, you sign him in and redirect. Otherwise, you need to store omniauth payload in the session, and redirect to a form where user can add an email:

```
def twitter
  if User.find_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    # sign in user and redirect
  else
    session[:omniauth] ||= {}
    session[:omniauth][auth.uid] = auth
    redirect_to new_omniauth_email_request_path(ominauth_uid: auth.uid)
  end
end

private

def auth
  request.env['omniauth.auth']
end
```

When you add this to routes.rb:

```
resources :omniauth, only: [], param: :uid do
  resource :email_request, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

You will have these two new routes available:

```
omniauth_email_request     POST  /omniauth/:omniauth_uid/email_request(.:format)       email_requests#create
new_omniauth_email_request GET   /omniauth/:omniauth_uid/email_request/new(.:format)   email_requests#new
```

You need to create `EmailRequestsController` and implement `new` and `create` actions. Don't forget to clear the session after the user is successfully created:

```
def create
  # ...
  @user = User.create do |user|
    user.email = params['email']
    user.uid = params['omniauth_uid']
    user.name = session[:omniauth][user.uid].name
    # assign whatever else you may need from session[:omniauth][user.uid]
  end

  session[:omniauth].delete @user.uid if @user.persisted?
  # ...
end
```

Please note that if you plan to support multiple omniauth providers, that on the "middle step" the user may provide an email that already exists in the database (for example the user has already authenticated via some other omniauth that passed the email). This case needs to be handled.